# Mailchimp Super Slim Subscribe Form - Horizontal Layout

Tags: html, css, forms, magento, mailchimp

I'd like to get this form on a 960px wide responsive magento site that has a smallest size of 320px.

I'd very much like it act/style similar to the newsletter form on [VintageStyler](http://vintagestyler.co.uk) - If you load the page and scroll to the bottom, you will see a newsletter signup form for email submission. I would like to have my form show in one line, and be responsive, like this one.

Check out my current form > [The Signup Form](http://a142501.sb1.dev.codeanywhere.net/mailchimp/) - currently "3 rows" that I would like to see in one long horizontal format - until it appears on smaller screens

This is the "super slim" form provided by mailchimp, with all styling included, instead of pulling from their remote CSS

Below is the code I am using

```
<head>
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{/*background:#fff;*/ clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  width:960px;}
#mc_embed_signup form {display:block; position:relative; text-align:left; /*padding:10px 0 10px 3%*/}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {font-weight:bold; padding:0; margin:15px 0; font-size:1.4em;}
#mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox]{-webkit-appearance:checkbox;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio]{-webkit-appearance:radio;}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
/* Button Code */#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #aaa; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#777;}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
#mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display:inline;}

#mc_embed_signup label {display:block; font-size:16px; padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold;}
#mc_embed_signup input.email {display:block; padding:8px 0; margin:0 4% 10px 0; text-indent:5px; width:35%; min-width:130px;}
#mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block; width:35%; margin:0 0 10px 0; min-width:90px;}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {float:left; top:-1.4em; padding:0em .5em 0em .5em; overflow:hidden; width:90%;margin: 0 5%; clear: both;}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {margin:1em 0; padding:1em .5em .5em 0; font-weight:bold; float:left; top:-1.5em; z-index:1; width:80%;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {color:#529214; display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin-left:1.05em; text-align:left; padding:.5em 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="#" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Stay Connected with Tuga Sunwear</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="#" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

If you want to toy around with this and post back here, that would be awesome. I can't seem to figure out why inline-block and getting rid of floats won't solve this.

Thanks again!

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My apologies. I just updated the post and hopefully clarified what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really looking for a tutorial in responsive design, so I suggest you read up on what's involved in that. But here's a basic example of what you need: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/JDrhG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
    *, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
    #mc_embed_signup{ clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;}
    #mc_embed_signup form {display:block; position:relative; text-align:left;}
    #mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
    #mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
    #mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #aaa; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
    #mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#777;}
    #mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
    #mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
    #mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display: inline-block; width: 31%; vertical-align: top;}

    #mc_embed_signup label {display:inline-block; font-size:16px; padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold; width: 31%;vertical-align: top;}
    #mc_embed_signup input.email {display:inline-block; padding:8px 0; margin:0 10px 10px 0; text-indent:5px; width:34%;vertical-align: top;}
    #mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block; width:100%; margin:0 0 10px 0;}

    @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
        #mc_embed_signup {width: 100%;}
        #mc_embed_signup label, #mc_embed_signup input.email, #mc_embed_signup .clear {display: block; width: 100%;}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Stay Connected with Tuga Sunwear</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
            <input type="text" name="#" tabindex="-1" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

You will need to integrate this with your layout, though, so things will need to be changed.